# Linear Search, repeated enter target until 0

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, break

The program is supposed to prompt the user to enter a target, the program then prints the index of the number in the list or -1 if the target is not in the list. If the user enters 0 the program stops and returns nothing. This is what I have so far and have tried many different versions but I cannot get the program to quit after 0 is entered. Edited- without while loop.

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
target=int(input("Enter a target: "))
def search(target,alist):    
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if target==0:
            return " "
            break
        elif target==alist[i]:
            return i
    return -1
        

print(search(target,alist))
```

Comment: Your just defining a function and returning from that, there isn't a return that actually breaks the loop. Also the returns directly after a return will never get hit.

Comment: For starters, get that function _out of the loop_, and you have to _call_ it inside the loop, and do something with the value it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop when searching in list in python.

I've changed the code:

```
def search(alist):
    while True:
        target = int(input("Enter a target: "))
        if target == 0:
            return
        elif target in alist:
            print(alist.index(target))
        else:
            print(-1)


alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
search(alist)

#  Output
# Enter a target: 2
# 1
# Enter a target: 4
# 3
# Enter a target: 10
# -1
# Enter a target: 11
# -1
# Enter a target: 0
# 
# Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: How could I do this if the def search had to be at (target,alist)?

Comment: Why does it have to pass target as an argument?